# Team Foundation 2012 My Work Report

Tags: visual-studio-2012

For the life of me I can't find any documentation on how to See the Work items in the new "my work" feature in 2012. I want this to ultimately be in a SSRS report.

I've looked everywhere in the warehouse as well as sql db. I've also looked for documentation and can't find any. I have also looked at the object model and although I can find traces thereof there isn't nearly enough to let me know where I can find this.

I think this is an excellent dashboard to see what my developers are currently working on, any suggestions as to where I can look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default this is meant for your personal work items and not for monitoring all your developers work items. However since it is query based you can modify the query based as per your needs. Click the `Open Query` under any of the categories in your `My Work` pane and modify it to whatever suites you.

Comment: Understood but it's an excellent tool for monitoring? I would like this to be in an SSRS report however.

Comment: Like I said it is not designed to be used for monitoring. Move to >3 developers and you will see what I mean. For monitoring see your product backlog dashboard and Kanban boards on your web access portal instead

Comment: Can you perhaps expand a bit on "you will see what I mean as getting another resource to see what you mean is a bit on the expensive side :-)"

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr you need to try it out. I have provided my perspective and alternatives. You may find it to be right or wrong only after you experiment your particular needs. And what I was referring to was the fact that this window is limited in size and suites a single dev's items rather than a whole team's items

Comment: Ok cool. You definitely have valid arguments but I will hold out for a while to see if there is a plausible solution before marking yours. Thanks